# Prove there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)-f(a)=(c-a)f'(c).$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

## Problem

Assume $f(x)$ is differentiable over $[a,b]$ and $f'(a)=f'(b)$. Prove there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $$f(c)-f(a)=(c-a)f'(c).$$

**Please notice that this is not Lagrange's Mean Value theorem at all.**

## Proof

Denote$$g(x):=\begin{cases}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a},&x \in (a,b],\\f'(a),&x=a.\end{cases}$$Then $g(x)$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and differentiable over $(a,b)$. In order to prove the original consequence, it is sufficient to show that $$\exists c \in (a,b):g'(c)=0.\tag{*}$$ According to the continuity of $g(x)$ over such a closed interval, it can achieve its maximum and minimum values over $[a,b]$. If it achieve such a value (no matter it is maximum or minimum) over $(a,b)$, then by Fermat's Lemma, $(*)$ holds. If not, without loss of generality, we assume $$\forall x \in [a,b]:g(a)\leq g(x)\leq g(b),\tag{**}$$ the right hand of which can be rewritten as$$\forall x \in [a,b]:f(x)\leq f(a)+(x-a)g(b).$$Thus，$$\forall x \in [a,b):\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}\geq \frac{f(b)-f(a)-(x-a)g(b)}{b-x}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=g(b).$$Taking the limits when $x \to b$，we obtain$f'(b)\geq g(b)$，and therefore $$g(a)=f'(a)=f'(b)\geq g(b).\tag{***}$$ Combining with  $(**)$, we can see $g(x)$ is constant，and hence $\forall x \in (a,b):g'(x)\equiv 0$，$(*)$ also holds. We are done.

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Regarding your tagging problems (:p) -- you'll want to enclose the tag in brackets, i.e. like `\tag{ * }`

Comment: This is the "mean value theorem" which classical proofs you can compare to yours.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, and I feel like the OP is probably aware of that; their question is simply about whether their proof is correct. Probably a proof assigned for a calculus or analysis class, more than likely.

Comment: @JeanMarie:  The classical mean value theorem states that $f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$ for some $c$. Unless I am mistaken, that is different from the above question.

Comment: The proof looks fine to me.

Comment: @OP - Martin brings up a fair point. In lieu of $c-a$ and $f(c)$ where $c \in (a,b)$, did you mean $b-a$ and $f(b)$ in the statement of the theorem?

Comment: please take care. Mine is not "Lagrange" at all.

Comment: @Martin R My bad, you are right.